Message: Is there a way of redacting the IP address with SMTP?
I don't know much about SMTP, but I understand that the IP address of the sender must be included in the headers. However, I also read that some email clients redact or hide the IP address of the client, similar to what happens when you send mail through a web interface.
Is there a way of doing this when sending mail through Emacs? What are my options?
My current settings are taken from the EmacsWiki:
(setq send-mail-function    'smtpmail-send-it
      smtpmail-smtp-server  "smtp.gmail.com"
      smtpmail-stream-type  'ssl
      smtpmail-smtp-service 465)

